# How to update record using Select Statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I wants to update like below.

```
update dbo.Record
set Alias = select alias from #tempRecord
WHERE Item = select Item from #tempRecord
```

I am using this one in trigger. even i tried like below

```
DECLARE @Alias nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ItemID INT

set @Alias = select alias from #tempRecord
```

**Error msg**

> incorrect syntax near SELECT

**Note**

> This table `#tempRecord` have only one row. Not multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
set @Alias = (select alias from #tempRecord)
```

or

```
SELECT @Alias = alias 
from #tempRecord;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the value of a SELECT statement you have to put them in parantheses, like so:

```
set @Alias = (select alias from #tempRecord)
```

But you have to keep in mind that this works only if your SELECT returns a single value.

For your UPDATE you probably better use a JOIN:

```
update dbo.Record
set Alias = T.alias
from dbo.Record R
    INNER JOIN #tempRecord T ON T.Item = R.Item
```